# Is it possible to retrieve Facebook status using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm trying to make an API call to Facebook to retrieve my status and display it on my website.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Facebook Javascript client library.  There's a stable version and a new alpha version.  Looks like you want the client library to access their RESTful API.

Here's all the pieces

- http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JavaScript_Client_Library
- http://github.com/facebook/connect-js
- http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JavaScript_SDK_%28Open_Source%29
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.ApiClient
- http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo

Answer (score 1):

those links seem outdated, try the graph api.

sample code:

`var fbObj = 'http://graph.facebook.com/brianyang1&callback=?';
$.getJSON(fbObj, function(json) {
  $('#output').html(json.first_name);
});`